# signed:ness optimization "bug" in gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, warnings

my code has a warning and I don't know how to avoid it. Here is a code snippet

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main(void) {
        uint16_t portnbr=0;
        uint16_t n_portnbr = htons(portnbr);
        return n_portnbr;
}
```

Compiler:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -Wconversion -Wall  -O2 a.cpp
```

Output:

```
a.cpp:4: warning: conversion to 'short unsigned int' from 'int' may alter its value
```

Is it possible to avoid the warning? *No option to modify the CFLAGS*.

My compiler is gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux)

Comment: I don't get that warning with gcc 4.1.2 or 4.7 -- and you shouldn't, at least not on line 4 (the declaration of `n_portnbr`).  `htons()` returns a `uint16_t`, which is likely `short unsigned int`, and you're assigning that result to a `uint16_t` object.  The `#include <arpa/inet.h>` should give you the proper declaration of `htons()`.  The `return` statement *could* be a problem, but I don't get a warning about that -- and apparently neither do you.  Did you copy-and-paste your *exact* code?

Comment: How is `htons()` declared on your system?

Comment: extern uint16_t htons (uint16_t __hostshort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in glibc.  See this [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44924).

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency the `htons` and relatives are often overloaded by macros. Try something like

```
uint16_t n_portnbr = (htons)(portnbr);
```

to see see if this solves your problem, this syntax makes sure to trigger the function and not the macro.

If this is the case here it is really a pity that they got it wrong. You should then try to switch off that macro just for that version.

Comment: this one worked. Eliminated my warning but I need to check at runtime also.

Comment: @cateof, what do you need to check at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Could simply be a missing prototype, that's what the warning sounds like.

Try manually declaring the `htons()` function, and see if that helps. If so, you need to investigate your headers.

[The Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) for `htons()` claims:

> POSIX.1-2001.
>
> Some systems require the inclusion of <netinet/in.h> instead of <arpa/inet.h>.

**UPDATE**: As pointed out in a comment, this is is C++ so it shouldn't "suffer" from implicit declarations of functions. Strange. I would recommend reading the pre-processed code, perhaps `htons()` is a macro which is behaving strangely for some reason.

Comment: That was my immediate reaction too, but at least from the looks of things, he's compiling as C++, which shouldn't allow the call at all without a prototype.